# Basic Javascript Program, help need

Tags: javascript

My program needs to consist of a for loop, use both input functions already created ( name and number) and totals need to be acquired. I also need to be able to CANCEL and go to my doc.write where i would input name and number. I also need to give the user another chance to type in their name or number if they accidentally typed in number where letters should be and vise-versa. I think i have majority of the structure right, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function inputName() {

var nameIn = prompt("Enter your Name");
while(!isNaN(nameIn)) {
nameIn = prompt("Must contain only letters");


}
return nameIn;

}
/* INPUT NUMBER */

 function inputNum(){

var numIn=parseFloat(prompt("Enter the number of hours worked \n 0-60 hours"));

var min=0;
var max=60;

while(numIn>min && numIn>max ){
numIn=prompt("Enter a valid number between 0-60");
return numIn;
}
</script>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">

//DECLARATIONS
var wage=10.00;
var earned; // hrsWrked*wage
var totHrsWrked=0;
var totEarning=0;
var BR= "
";
var howMany;
var loopControl;

//INPUT & PROCESSING

howMany=parseFloat(prompt("How many employees are you inputing?"));

for(loopControl=1 ; loopControl <= howMany; ++loopControl){

var inpNam=inputName();

var inpNumber=inputNum();


earned= inpNumber*wage;
totEarning+=earned;
totHrsWrked+=inpNumber;

//OUTPUT
document.write("Name: "+ inpNam+ BR);
document.write("Hours Worked: " + inpNumber + BR);
document.write("Money Earned: $ " + earned + BR +BR);

}
document.write("Total Hours Worked: " + totHrsWrked.toFixed(2) + BR);
document.write("Total Earnings: " + "$"+totEarning.toFixed(2)+ BR+BR);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format your code properly - this will make your question easier to read and understand.

Comment: I don't think that `!isNan(name)` will find if it is only letters, a regex would be better suited towards that

Comment: also, the way you defined `BR` will not actually create a line break, you should do this: `var BR='<br>'` and that will cause a newline

Answer (score 0):

Here's the edited version of your code. :)

```
<! doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<script>

//DECLARATIONS
var wage=10.00, earned, totHrsWrked=0, totEarning=0, howMany;

//INPUT & PROCESSING
howMany=parseFloat(prompt("No of employees"));
for( var loopControl=1 ; loopControl <= howMany; ++loopControl)
{

    var inpNam=inputName();
    var inpNumber=inputNum();   
    earned= inpNumber*wage;
    totEarning+= (+earned);
    totHrsWrked+= (+inpNumber);
    //OUTPUT
    document.write("Name: "+ inpNam+ "<br>");       
    document.write("\n Hours Worked: " + inpNumber + "<br>");
    document.write("Money Earned: $ " + earned + "<br><br>");
}
document.write("Total Hours Worked: " + totHrsWrked.toFixed(2)+ "<br>");
document.write("Total Earnings: " + "$"+totEarning.toFixed(2)+ "<br>");

//INPUT NAME 
function inputName() {

var nameIn = prompt("Enter your Name");
while(!isNaN(nameIn)) {
nameIn = prompt("Must contain only letters");
}
return nameIn;
}

//INPUT NUMBER 
function inputNum(){
var numIn=parseFloat(prompt("Enter the number of hours worked \n 0-60 hours"));
var min=0;
var max=60;

while(numIn<=min || numIn>=max ){
numIn=prompt("Enter a valid number between 0-60");
}
return numIn;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```